# Any info related to an LG API/SDK for their latest washers and dryers?

Tags: sdk, iot, lg

I've seen info related to smart TVs but nothing related to washing machines and dryers. I'm looking to prototype an app.

FYI: I run the LG Smart Laundry apps on a Samsung Galaxy S6 and an iPhone 6. The Android app is more feature complete. My washer is a WM5000HVA and the dryer is a DLX5000V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are looking for web service APIs or the actual source code for the machines.   I found the following site:

http://opensource.lge.com/osSch/list?curPage=22&types=NAME&%C2%ADamp;search=d856

But this looks like the source code to run the actual machines.